# How to search requested page through dropdown lists by selecting categories?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have four dropdownlists and one button in my application.
1'st dropdown contains available product details like tv, cars, laptops, mobiles.
2'nd dropdown contains available product company details like Samsung, Dell, Bmw, Nokia.
3'rd dropdown contains the product model like Nokia 1110, Bmw x5, Dell Vostro 1550 like that.
4'th dropdown contains the city names like Hyderabad, Mumbai, Kolkatha.

If the user selects the first dropdown as car, the car companies available should be opened in a second dropdown and if the user sets the second dropdown as Bmw, third dropdown should show the models available in Bmw. Fourth dropdown should display the cities in India if the user selects Hyderabad as the city. Details about Bmwx5 in Hyderabad page should be opened.

Comment: you want to this on client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

If i properly understand your question the answer would be your have four dropdowns

***ids >> a,b,c,d***

now

---

### 1st dropdown

```
 <asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_select_changed1" ID="a" runat="server">
    now in your code file 
    protected void ddl_select_changed1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//change b,c,d dropdowns
     }
```

### Now another one

### 2st dropdown

```
 <asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_select_changed2" ID="b" runat="server">
    now in your code file 
    protected void ddl_select_changed2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//change c,d dropdowns
     }
```

Now another one

---

### 3rd dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_select_changed3" ID="b" runat="server">
    now in your code file 
    protected void ddl_select_changed3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//change d dropdowns
     }
```

This is the way you can achieve your requirement i hope this would help you....regards...:)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but sure this is what you are looking for:

CODE BEHIND CHANGES:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Bind data to first drop down box on pageload
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ItemName";//field returned from db
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ItemID";//field returned from db
    //binds to data returned from db - first items have no parent id's
    DropDownList1.DataSource = GetItems(0);
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Borgs", Session["BorgID"].ToString()));
    DropDownList1.Items[0].Selected = true;
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //When value is selected in first drop down populate second drop down using the id selected in first drop down
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "ItemName";//field returned from db
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ItemID";//field returned from db
    //binds to data returned from db
    DropDownList2.DataSource = GetItems(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.DataValueField));
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("[Choose]", "-1"));
    DropDownList2.Items[0].Selected = true;
}
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //When value is selected in second drop down populate third drop down using the id selected in second drop down
    DropDownList3.DataTextField = "ItemName";//field returned from db
    DropDownList3.DataValueField = "ItemID";//field returned from db
    //binds to data returned from db
    DropDownList3.DataSource = GetItems(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.DataValueField));
    DropDownList3.DataBind();
    DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("[Choose]", "-1"));
    DropDownList3.Items[0].Selected = true;
}

public DataTable GetItems(int _ParentItemID)
{
    SqlConnection sqlconn = null;

    sqlconn = new SqlConnection();
    //SQLConnectionstring declared in web.config to connect to db
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionstring"].ConnectionString;

    //select data from database
    SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ItemName, ItemID  FROM YourTable WHERE ParentItemID = " + _ParentItemID, sqlconn);

    sqlcommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
    //create and fill datatable to return results to call and bind
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    sqlconn.Dispose();
    sqlconn.Close();

    return dt;
}
```

FRONT END CHANGES:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```